# Copying an entire column using OpenPyXL in Python 3

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy an entire column over using OpenPyXL. Google seems to offer a lot of examples using ranges, but not for an entire column.

I have a workbook with a single worksheet with a load of dates in column A and column JX (A contains monthly dates, JX contains quarterly dates). I want the monthly dates column (in A:A) to be copied over to each worksheet ending in 'M' in my target workbook, and the quarterly dates column (in JX:JX) to the worksheets ending in 'Q'.

However, for some reason the last nested for loop, `for src, dst in zip(ws_base[monthRange], ws_target['A:A']):` is only copying the first cell, and nothing else. It looks like I'm identifying the correct column with my `monthRange` and `quarterRange` strings, but Python isn't looping through the whole column despite the fact that I've got two ranges defined.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
# Load the target workbook
targetwb = openpyxl.load_workbook('pythonOutput.xlsx')


# Load the source workbook
wb_base = openpyxl.load_workbook('Baseline_IFRS9_' + reportingMonth+'.xlsx')

# Go to row 9 and find "Geography:" to identify the relevant 
# month and quarter date columns

sentinel = u"Geography:"
ws_base = wb_base.active

found = 0
dateColumns = []

for column in ws_base:
    for cell in column:
        if cell.value == sentinel:
            dateColumns.append(cell.column) #
            found + 1

            if found == 2:
                break


ColumnM = dateColumns[0]
ColumnQ = dateColumns[1]

print('Monthly col is ' + ColumnM)
print('Quarterly col is ' + ColumnQ)

IndexM = int(openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string(str(ColumnM)))
IndexQ = int(openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string(str(ColumnQ)))

print('Monthly col index is ' + str(IndexM))
print('Quarterly col index is ' + str(IndexQ))

print('Proceeding to paste into our new workbook...')

sheetLoop = targetwb.get_sheet_names()


for sheets in sheetLoop:
    if sheets.endswith('Q'):
        ws_target = targetwb[sheets]
        quarterRange = ColumnQ + ':' + ColumnQ

        print('Copying and pasting quarterly dates into: ' + sheets)
        for src, dst in zip(ws_base[quarterRange], ws_target['A:A']):
            dst.value = src.value

    elif sheets.endswith('M'):
        ws_target = targetwb[sheets]
        monthRange = ColumnM + ':' + ColumnM

        print('Copying and pasting monthly dates into: ' + sheets)
        for src, dst in zip(ws_base[monthRange], ws_target['A:A']):
            dst.value = src.value

targetwb.save('pythonOutput.xlsx')
```

Here's a simpler form of my problem.

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('pythonInput.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('pythonOutput.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for src, dst in zip(ws1['A:A'], ws2['B:B']):
    print( 'Printing from ' + str(src.column) + str(src.row) + ' to ' + str(dst.column) + str(dst.row))
    dst.value = src.value

wb2.save('test.xlsx')
```

So the problem here is that the for loop only prints from A1 to B1. Shouldn't it be looping down across rows..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a new XLSX in a spreadsheet editor, you see lots and lots of empty cells in a grid. However, these empty cells are actually omitted from the file, and they will be only written once they have a non-empty value. You can see for yourself: XLSX is essentially a bunch of ZIP-compressed XMLs, which can be opened with any archive manager.

In a similar fashion, new cells in OpenPyXL are only created when you access them. The `ws2['B:B']` range only contains one cell, B1, and `zip` stops when the shortest iterator is exhausted.

With this in mind, you can iterate through the source range and use explicit coordinates to save the values in correct cells:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('pythonInput.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('pythonOutput.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for cell in ws1['A:A']:
    print('Printing from ' + str(cell.column) + str(cell.row))
    ws2.cell(row=cell.row, column=2, value=cell.value)

wb2.save('test.xlsx')
```