# How to write the data that has been read into a certain column using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I cannot figure out how to write the data that has been read below to a certain column, such as column F. Column B has been read and I want to paste it in the same workbook into column F. Eventually I would create a function because I would be doing the reading and writing columns multiple times.

```
import openpyxl
import os

# Finds current directory
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)

# Changes directory
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Shane\\Documents\\Exel Example')

# prints new current directory
new_path = os.getcwd()
print(new_path)

# load workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
type(wb)

# load worksheet
ws1 = wb.active

# read sheet names
sht_names = wb.sheetnames
print(sht_names)

# ***reads and prints column B***
col_b = list(ws1.columns)[1]

for cellObj in col_b:
    print(cellObj.value)

# write column b's contents into column F
```

Comment: Checkout this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620532/copying-an-entire-column-using-openpyxl-in-python-3

Comment: for c1, c2 in zip(ws['B'], ws['F']): c2.value = c1.value

Comment: @CharlieClark that code did it, thank you for your help! My project will cut off significant time and money!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

t = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
s = t.active # get the active worksheet
lst = list(s.columns)
lst_row = list(s.rows)
cellA1 = s[1][0] 
rowA = s[1]
g = (x.value for x in lst[1]) # column b?
for item in g:
    print (item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have the information in column B. I just need to paste it, or write it into column F.

col_b = list(sht_1.columns)[1]

This line of code is what read the information, now I just need to paste or write it.

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I am new here. I have updated the question and the source code to give a more elaborate question.