# Python: copy/paste columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with an excel file using openpyxl. I want to copy all the formulas I have in column GD and paste them in column GE in the same excel tab. How can I do this so the formulas update in the new column?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
sheet= workbook.worksheets[8]
sheet.insert_cols(187)
sheet.column_dimensions['GE'].width= 14.55
sheet.column_dimensions['GG'].width= 14.55
sheet.column_dimensions['GF'].width= 14.55
sheet.column_dimensions['GH'].width= 3
```

Many solutions show how to copy a column and paste in another tab of the excel file but I need to copy and paste in the same sheet.

Here's an updated code

```
for cell in sheet['GD3:GD67322']:
print(str(cell.column) + str(cell.row))
sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=187, value=cell.value)
```

What else needs to be changed in that code if I want GD3:GD67322 to be pasted in column GE at row 3?

Comment: Try looking at [Copying an entire column using OpenPyXL in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48620532/16653700).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying an entire column using OpenPyXL in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620532/copying-an-entire-column-using-openpyxl-in-python-3)

Comment: You can change the code in the answer in the link to work for a single workbook. You can use `for cell in sheet['A:A']:
    print('Printing from ' + str(cell.column) + str(cell.row))
    sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=2, value=cell.value)` and change the column and ['A:A'] to match the columns you need to read and write to. Code from [Norrius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649499/16653700)

Comment: If you're copying formulae and need the references changing, you'll need to use the translate function of the tokeniser.

Comment: What is the current output of your code??